# Setters on objects Java

Tags: java, object, methods, increment, setter

Hello so I'm having a bit of difficulties with a setter method on objects.

```
public class Company {
    private  String companyName;
    public static int numberOfEmployees;
    public Employees employees[];

    public void setEmployees( String name, String heritage, String [] programmingLanguages, Salary d) {
      
        Employees employee1  = new Programmer(name, heritage,programmingLanguages, d,d.getBasicBrutoSalary());
        employees[numberOfEmployees] = employee1;
        numberOfEmployees++;

    }
```

So basicly this is a method defined in the 'company class' while making an Employees object who's using the parameters for making a 'Programmer'.

But that's not the deal, what I want tot do is by calling this setter method, automaticly create an object. So each time it's used, kind of increment the name of the object it's going to make.

So for example the first time I use it it makes an object called Employee1 and stores it in Employee[0].. second time I want it to store Employee2 into Employee[1].

Maybe I'm making this way too difficult but I'm just trying things out, and can't seem to find a way to make this work.

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that `setEmployees` is a bad name for something that *adds* an employee and that `Employees` should not be plural, I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: I would suggest working with an ArrayList instead, much easier for a situation like this. Also don't name a method like this `setEmployees` because getX/setX methods are for getting and setting an attribute, better to name it something like `addEmployee`

Comment: When you say "...increment the name of the object..." are you referring to the argument (`String name`) or the variable (`employee1`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that `Programmer` object is subclass of `Employees`, or else it will not work. More or less it should look like the following:

```
public class Company {
private  String companyName;
public static int numberOfEmployees;
public static Employees employees[];

public void setEmployees( String name, String heritage, String [] programmingLanguages, Salary d) {
    numberOfEmployees++;
    employees[numberOfEmployees] = new Programmer(name, heritage,programmingLanguages, d,d.getBasicBrutoSalary());;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!